# Método GET retornando vazio

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo um WebApi, estou utilizando a abordagem code-first, para isso utlizei o entity framework 6.0.1, no meu projeto possuo as seguintes classes PersonController.cs, Configurations.cs (onde insiro os dados manualmente por enquanto)e minha classe Person, estou utilizando o Postman para simular a requisição, procurei alguns exemplos aqui no site porém nenhum equivalente ao meu, caso alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

**PersonController.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApi.Models;
using WebApi.Contexto;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly Context contexto = new Context();
        [Route("api/person")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult getAll(string search)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                search = "";
            }
            var list = contexto.People.Where(x => x.firstName.Contains(search) || x.lastName.Contains(search));

            return Ok(list);

        } 
     }
}
```

**Configurations.cs**

```
namespace WebApi.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebApi.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApi.Contexto.Context>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(WebApi.Contexto.Context context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.

            context.People.Add(new Person { firstName = "Andrew ", lastName = "Teste", id = 1, birthDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 31) });
           
        }
    }
}
```

**Person.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quais testes foram feitos? Qual era o resultado esperado em cada caso?

Comment: Esperava que retorna-se um JSON no postman contento a informação da ultima linha da minha classe Configuration

Comment: E quais requests foram feitos e quais os valores que deveriam ser apresentados?

Comment: Só foi realizado o GET até o momento, porém ao invés dele retornar um array com as informações em um formato JSON ele só me retorna " [  ] "

Comment: E o que você está passando no parâmetro `search`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar a solução do erro, vou deixar aqui caso alguém passe pelo mesmo.
Na minha string de conexão eu esqueci o parâmetro:

`Integrated security = True`

Com isso não era possivel realizar a conexão com o banco de dados, ja que estou utilizando Windows Authenticate.

Apóes essa correção é so roda esse comando:

`update-database`